# Problem deleting files in python starting with digits

Tags: python, command-line, operating-system

I'm trying to delete files using python.
I tried deleting using os library and shutil but in both ways the file was not found even though the path was correct. The file name begins with digits and when I manually changed it's name my program did find it and deleted it.
In addition i tried changing the file name using os but that didn't work either.
After that I wrote a function that try to delete it using the command line and it didn't work as well.

```
import subprocess
import os

def delete_with_command_line(file_path):
    try:
        subprocess.run(['del', file_path], check=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        print(f"{file_path} has been successfully deleted.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error deleting {file_path}: {e.stderr}")
```

original function

```
def delete_files(work_folder):
    keep_files = ['ion.tsv', 'peptide.tsv', 'protein.fasta', 'protein.tsv', 'psm.tsv']
    files_to_delete = [f for f in os.listdir(work_folder) if f not in keep_files]

    for file_to_delete in files_to_delete:
        file_path = os.path.join(work_folder, file_to_delete)
        print("file to delete: " + file_to_delete)
        try:
            os.remove(file_path)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"File not found: {file_path}")
        except PermissionError as pe:
            print(f"Permission error deleting file {file_path}: {pe}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting file {file_path}: {e}")
```